# Karaf with UTF-8

Tags: java, utf-8, environment-variables, karaf

If I start Karaf (2.3.4) and the following environment is set

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

It is not possible, anymore to use the up and down arrow to get the last command (in the karaf command line), is this a bug I should report or isn't it allowed to use this option with karaf?

Comment: Done, see: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KARAF-2827